# Find the surface area of the circumcyclinder

Tags: spheres

The surface area of a sphere with radius $r$ is $4 \pi r^2 $. Find the surface area of its circumscribing cylinder.

I don't know to begin the problem. I would highly value your hints

Comment: What is the circumcylinder?

Comment: The cylinder which the sphere can be dipped into

Comment: So your question is to find the surface area for a cylinder of radius $r$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I deleted that comment. It should be: height of the cylinder = $2r$ and radius = $r$.

Comment: Yes, what @user366082 was supposed to discover is the wonderful fact that Archimedes knew that the sphere and the cylinder have precisely the same surface area.

Comment: @TedShifrin are the surface areas the same so that i can factor

Comment: Well, it's not clear if the OP meant the lateral area or the total area.

Comment: What do you mean, @user366082?

Answer (score 0):

Interpretation of *"Circumscribing Cylinder"* used in your question:

> Smallest possible cyclinder which can contain a given sphere

Sphere radius = $r$

So cylinder radius = $r$

Cylinder height = $2$  $\times$ sphere radius = $2r$

Cylinder surface area is equal to $2$ times the surface area of an end circle, plus the curved rectangular surface.

Ends: $2 \times \pi r^2$

Rectangle: $2r \times 2\pi r$

Surface area = $2\pi r^2 + 4\pi r^2 = 6\pi r^2$